# How to create a QFrame in the middle of another QFrame?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtgui, qlayout

Can I use the Qt to do the things below:

I need two `QFrame`s, one (child) is in the middle of another (parent), and when I change the parent `QFrame`, the children will resize too.

How can I set the layout or other thing can do like that.

Just like the picture below， the yellow is child， the white is parent.

[image]

Comment: You create a `QFrame` object, set a layout to it, and add another `QFrame` object inside that layout. What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's be two QFrame... But the first answer is better.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFrame f1;
    f1.setStyleSheet( "background: white" );

    QFrame f2;
    f2.setStyleSheet( "background: yellow" );

    QHBoxLayout l( &f1 );
    l.setContentsMargins( 10, 10, 10, 10);
    l.addWidget( &f2 );

    f1.resize( 200, 200 );
    f1.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to find one solution like below.

```
QFrame *parent_frame = new QFrame(this);//this means parent_frame's parent widget
QFrame *child_frame = new QFrame(parent_frame);

child_frame ->setFixedSize(parent_frame->geometry().width() - 4, parent_frame->geometry().height() - 4);
child_frame ->move(2,2);
```

and rewrite the resizeEvent event of the parent_frame's parent widget,do the same thing

```
child_frame ->setFixedSize(parent_frame->geometry().width() - 4, parent_frame->geometry().height() - 4);
child_frame ->move(2,2);
```

the only thing you need to be careful to do the first setfixedsize after you do this.show() so that it can get the right width and height.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFrame>

namespace {
    static const auto STYLE_SHEET = "QFrame#MyFrame {border: 10px solid white; background: yellow}";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFrame f;
    f.setObjectName( QStringLiteral( "MyFrame" ) );
    f.setStyleSheet( STYLE_SHEET );
    f.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Your answer only contains a single `QFrame`. The OP asked about nested `QFrame`s.